# How to specify startup priorities in Kubernetes on Azure?

Tags: kubernetes, azure, azure-kubernetes-service

I have a Kubernetes cluster running on Azure, it has two Deployment pods a database and a Tomcat application server. Problem is that when I start the cluster, sometimes the application starts before Tomcat, and in the application startup I have a function that accesses the database, and the function fails because it cannot connect.

Ideally, I would define a dependency that the Tomcat application server starts after the database pod. Is there a way to specify priorities in Azure Kubernetes deployments yaml?